# How to return list of records along with latest of related record using LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

Im new to LINQ and am struggling to find out how to do the following.

I have a system that has a sql server back end and it uses EF5 to interact with the database.  I have  the following tables

```
Case 
CaseStatus
Status
CaseAction
ActionType
```

Relationships are...

```
Case (1 - many) CaseStatus
CaseStatus (1 - many) CaseAction
Status (1 - many) CaseStatus
ActionType (1 - many) CaseAction
```

I need to display a list of Case records that  includes the latest Status (based on the last CaseStatus record related to the case) and the latest Action record (based on the latest CaseAction record related to the latest CaseStatus record related to the case)

All cases will have at least on CaseStatus record but not all CaseStatus records will have related CaseAction records.  In these scenarios I still need to display some details from the Case record but I will leave the Action column blank

In T-SQL this is the sort of thing that would give me what I want

```
select 
    c.ID            CaseID
    ,cs1.Name       CurrentStatus
    ,cs1.Date       StatusDate
    ,ca1.Name       LatestAction
    ,ca1.Date       ActionDate

from 
    [Case] c
    left join 
    --Latest CaseStatus record to get current status of case
    (
    select
        cs.ID
        ,cs.CaseID
        ,s.Name 
        ,cs.Date
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by caseid order by cs.id desc) rn
    from
        CaseStatus cs
        --Join to status to get the name of the statusID
        inner join Status s on cs.StatusID=s.ID

    )   cs1
    on c.ID=cs1.CaseID and cs1.rn=1


left join 
    --Latest CaseAction on the case
    (
    select
        ca.CaseStatusID
        ,at.Name    
        ,ca.Date
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by casestatusID order by ca.id desc) rn
    from
        CaseAction ca
        inner join ActionType at on ca.ActionTypeID=at.ID

    ) ca1
    on ca1.CaseStatusID=cs1.ID and ca1.rn=1
```

I know that one thing I could do to get my data into my application is to include the view that contains this SQL in my EF model.

What I'd like, for the purposes of learning is to be able to achieve the same results using LINQ.  If possible I would really like to see examples using the comprehensive syntaxt and the extension method syntax

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to come up with the following that seems to give me what I need.  Thanks for pointers guys

```
var cases = db.Cases
    .Select(c => new
        {
            CaseID = c.ID,
            LatestStatus = c.CaseStatus
                    .Where(cs => cs.CaseID == c.ID)
                    .OrderByDescending(cs => cs.ID)
                    .FirstOrDefault()
        })
        .Select(c => new
            {
                CaseID = c.CaseID,
                CurrentStatus = c.LatestStatus.Status.Name,
                LatestAction = c.LatestStatus.CaseActions
                            .Where(ca => ca.CaseStatusID == c.LatestStatus.ID)
                            .OrderByDescending(ca => ca.ID)
                            .FirstOrDefault()
        })
        .Select(c => new CaseListItem
                        {
                            CaseID = c.CaseID,
                            CurrentStatus = c.CurrentStatus,
                            LastAction = c.LatestAction != null ? c.LatestAction.ActionType.Name : "-",
                            ActionDate = c.LatestAction != null ? c.LatestAction.Date : null
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you have a `Case` class that has a `Statuses` property, which is a collection of `CaseStatus` objects. Also that the `CaseStatus` object has a `Status` property and a collection of `CaseAction` objects called Actions. I'll also assume that you have a `DbContext`-descendant entity called `context` through which you access the data.

In that case the queries are relatively simple:

```
context.Cases.Select( c=> {
   //get the last status
   var lastStatus = c.Statuses.OrderByDescending(cs => cs.ID).First();
   //get the last action (might be null)
   var lastAction = lastStatus.OrderByDescending(ca => ca.ID).FirstOrDefault();
   return new 
   {
      CaseID = c.ID,
      StatusName = lastStatus.Status.Name,
      StatusDate = lastStatus.Date,
      ActionName = (lastAction == null) ? null : lastAction.Action.Name,
      ActionDate = (lastAction == null) ? null : lastAction.Date,
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for response SWeko.

Comment: Thanks for response @SWeko. Unfortunately this does not work.  After changing the line  

`var lastAction = lastStatus..OrderByDescending(ca => ca.ID).FirstOrDefault();`

to var lastAction = lastStatus.Actions.OrderByDescending(ca => ca.ID).FirstOrDefault(); 

I got an error stating
A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Comment: Apologies for formatting - I am new to site and heve not yet mastered the Markdown :-(

Comment: this did put me on the track to come up with the following

Comment: this did put me on the track to come up with the following .... mmm it seems my response is too long.  NOt sure how to overcome the max characters constraint on comments.  Essentially my solution followed this sort of pattern  

    var cases = db.Cases
        .Select(c => new
            {                                CaseID = c.ID,
                                LatestStatus = c.CaseStatus.Where(cs => cs.CaseID == c.ID).OrderByDescending(cs => cs.ID).FirstOrDefault()

                            })
                            .Select...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't an equivalent to ROW_NUMBER in linq.

You would need to use a couple of groupjoins in linq to achieve the same result.
Groupjoin combined with DefaultIfEmpty equates to a left join in SQL (and is sent as such in raw SQL) See Microsoft example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx

So in comprehensive syntax it would be:

```
var q = from c in db.Cases
        join cs1 in 
        (  
            from cs in db.CaseStatus.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
            join s in db.Status on cs.StatusId equals s.ID
            join ca1 in
            (
              from ca in db.CaseAction.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
              join a in db.Action on ca.ActionId equals a.ID
              select new {ca, ActionName = a.Name} 
            )
            on cs.ID equals ca1.ca.CaseStatusID
            into caGrp
            from caDft in caGrp.FirstOrDefault()
            select new {cs, 
                        StatusName = s.Name, 
                        LastActionName = (caDft==null? String.Empty : caDft.ActionName)
                        LastActionDate = (caDft==null? String.Empty : caDft.ca.Date)
                       }
        ) on c.ID equals cs1.cs.CaseId
        into csGrp
        from csDft in csGrp.First()
        select new {c, csDft};
 return q.ToList().Select(x => new{
                                   CaseID = x.c.ID, 
                                   StatusName = x.csDft.StatusName,
                                   StatusDate = x.csDft.cs.Date,
                                   ActionName = x.csDft.LastActionName,
                                   ActionDate = x.csDft.LastActionDate
                                  });
```

Note - its not quite pure comprehensive linq, as I've used the OrderByDescending extension methods, but close enough ;) I'll leave the extension methods version to someone else

Comment: Thanks for response James.  I made a few mods to match with my object names  

Having made these adjustments I get a compile error on line  
`join s in db.Status on cs.StatusID equals  x.ID`  
stating that  
The name 'x' is not in scope on the right side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'  
Swapping makes no difference.  

Unfortunately my knowledge is such that Im not sure how to debug

Comment: Ah my mistake @Terry - x was not the thing to be joining on, it should have been s (and you need to have the left side of the join on the left side of the join condition too!) I've corrected it above

Comment: Thanks James.  I get an the following error `The argument to DbIsNullExpression must refer to a primitive, enumeration or reference type`.  This error disappears if I comment out `LastAction = x.csDft.caDft == null ? null : x.csDft.caDft.ActionName,
ActionDate = x.csDft.caDft == null ? null : x.csDft.caDft.ca.Date`.  Also, with these lines commented my query runs but returns more rows than I have Cases.  The number of rows indicates that the query is bringing back all related CaseStatus rows.  I must say I really struggle with this syntax but I appreciate your help

Comment: Hi @Terry - I'm not familiar with the first error you're seeing - but I assume it's because I did the null comparison after the query had been sent to the database rather than before (When .ToList() is called the query is sent to the database). I've altered the query to do the null comparison before that. Also I replaced 2 calls to .DefaultIfEmpty() with .First() and .FirstOrDefault() in the query to correct your 2nd problem. As I said before when you use .DefaultIfEmpty() it's equivalent to a left join - hence if there is more than 1 entry on the right side you get more than 1 row!

Comment: The comprehensive syntax does take a little while to get your head round (or it did for me) coming from an SQL background. Obviously the order of the keywords is different, but the main difference is sql queries return flat data, whereas LINQ returns objects (which can potentially have collection properties). It's the `into` keyword that projects one side of a join into a collection.

Comment: Thanks once again @James.  I've gone with the method I found but your answer was a good learning exercise for me